# Do I have to lock when several go routines write in channel

Tags: go, channel

Do I have to lock if two go routines write into the same channel or is this automatically handled by go?

Comment: Please don't add signatures to your post. [StackOverflow already shows one for you](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Channels are safe, it's built in.

Comment: @reen channels are used to get tasks given by different goroutines for example. That's an essential property of the language. I'd like to be able to propose a more detailed answer but I feel jnml's one is definitive. Almost nothing in Go makes sense without this assumption.

Comment: @reen you do not have to read the spec for that bit of information. The tutorial as well as effective Go (as linked) should make it very clear.